# How do I set the Android bash path in ZSH?

Tags: bash, unix, android, zsh

Looking through the [Cordova Android docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android), I see this line

> You need to add the path to your Android SDK platform-tools and tools directory. In my example I will use "/Development/android-sdk-macosx" as the directory the SDK is installed in. Add the following line:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/tools
```

How do I set that up in ZSH?

Answer (score 4):

I use this:

```
PATH=$PATH:"$HOME/Documents/Android/SDK/platform-tools"
```

Previously I had to use this to work *(when I re-installed the OS X and Zsh, the problem disappeared)*:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:$HOME/Documents/Android/SDK/platform-tools"
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the path didn't work for me.

However, I used homebrew to install the `android-sdk` brew. When you run `brew info android-sdk`, it suggests adding the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable to the `.bashrc` file. I added it to `.zshenv` instead.

In other words, I added the following line to `.zshenv`:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
```

I then opened a new console where I was able to run the cordova android commands successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same line, but put it in the `.zshenv` file in your home directory (or create that file if it doesn't already exist).

Comment: I have a .zshrc where my paths are set. I added the line there and it throws an error when I start my terminal (it's sourced on startup). I think it has something to do with quotation marks.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Weird. No more error, but when I ````which adt```` it says it's not found.

Comment: Figured it out. Had to add $HOME to the beginning of each segment. Also, the path for the SDK is wrong. 

```mac-x86_64/sdk/platform-tools:$HOME/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/tools```

Comment: @jjlin In Ubuntu 19.10, I create .zshenv as u said and wrote what I wrote in .bashrc to make it work, "export PATH=${PATH}:/home/pranav/platform-tools_r29.0.5-linux/platform-tools". But it didn't worked.